# Why it takes more time to write into hive stage directory using insertInto function in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am running below spark code, which writes into a hive partitioned table.

```
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).format("orc").insertInto("s**000h.test")
```

Internally all the executors are writing into the Hive stage area(.hive-staging_hive_2020-03-30_13-47-16_727_5670185411499574661-1)  and it is taking more time as compared to while I am writing data explicitly into an HDFS directory as given below.

`df.write.mode(mode).format("orc").partitionBy("dept_id").save(tempPath)`

The time difference is coming to be around 1 hr for 900 partitions.

Could you please explain this behavior.

Comment: Can you check the number of files written in each case?

Comment: @mazaneicha The number of files remains the same in both cases.

Comment: So whats that number? Also, after direct hdfs write, you must be running `MSCK REPAIR` before you can query Hive table, right? How long does that take?